# Co-authoring a paper with a persona non grata

Tags: ethics, authorship, collaboration

Suppose Researcher A did some joint work with Researcher B. While the work was still in progress, or the manuscript was in preparation, researcher B became persona non grata in Academia, due to wrongdoing. I don't think the exact nature of wrongdoing is relevant here, but let's say it is serious, as in for example:

- faking research results (the research with A was not faked)
- severely breaching research ethics (the research with A was not affected)
- sexual misconduct towards subordinates (that Researcher A was not aware of during joint work)

What's Researcher A to do? I see four options, all of which have their ethical and practical drawbacks.

- **publish the result jointly with B as planned.** The ethical drawback is that it can be perceived as siding with B in the scandal/breaching a boycott, and the  practical one is that Researcher A's career might suffer from association with the scandal.
- **not publish at all.** The practical drawback is that Researcher's A CV suffers, and the ethical drawbacks are obvious: not publishing a worthy research funded by taxpayers is a waste of their money; it may hinder further progress of the field, and, for example, in Maths, if results have been announced or communicated to the community, then codes of conduct explicitly require that the details are published soon.
- **withdraw Researcher A's name.** The practical drawback is as above, and the ethical drawback is that generally nobody should receive full credit for the work that was in fact joint, and even less so as a "reward" for the misconduct.
- **ask/pressure Researcher B to withdraw their name.** The practical concern is that Researcher B may not agree, and the ethical one is that, again, Researcher A should not get more credit than their contribution to the work, and wrongdoing should not disqualify B from getting their share of credit where it is due.

So, what is the right course of action for A, ethically and practically?

Comment: The question is very interesting, but you already give a self-contained answer. There is no perfect solution, all solutions will have substantial drawbacks, and one can only weigh-off the tradeoffs to pick the solution that aligns best with one's personal values.

Comment: You might consider posting the four possibilities as an answer instead. It is completely fine to ask and answer questions for the benefit of others. And maybe you'll get a different answer, who knows?

Comment: It might be relevant to mention your career stage in the question, if it does not break anonymity too much.

Comment: The three examples of misconduct are quite different, actually, and probably relevant.

Comment: Also has researcher A published with researcher B before? If so, as researcher A is already associated with B i might suggest being inclined to still publish (as long as A knows for sure that B didn't fake the data or breach ethics on this paper).

Comment: I think that in the case in which the misconduct is not directly on research ethics, then one should publish. Ex 3. Why A should be associated to B? Being A I would probably avoid future collaboration. And even this might be not ethnically perfect...

Comment: `faking research results (the research with A was not faked)` at least in some fields it would be very hard to say this confidently. And you would need to be *extremely* confident that you are correct in your assumption -- if you went ahead and published with someone you knew to be deceitful in some of their work , even a minor problem with your paper is going to make you look very bad.

Comment: Also I think if we are being honest the type of research matters, at least on a practical level.  I would have a much different response for someone doing research on a COVID vaccine than someone doing extremely obscure research that will probably be forgotten the day after it's published.

Comment: you can always throw out the portions that Researcher B, take some additional time and redo those portions yourself. This time with the advantage of experience so it should be much easier to perform.

Comment: @eps well it could be that A did all the actual work and collected data while B was the ideas person/helped write the paper/provided funding. Then, if B instead did all the data collection then it's alot easier as A to walk away if they where only the ideas person or helped with writing.

Comment: Unfortunately the type of misdemeanour *is* relevant although your reticence is understandable. For example fake results will result in all of B's work being suspect. It won't help much to say that in your case things were different. People will simply shy away from citing B's work. Thus publishing may result in your work being ignored. It's a really tough situation.

Comment: I have voted to close because the manner of the transgression is too important to answer generally.

Comment: I don't see how it would be morally wrong to collaborate with researcher B (unless their actions were so severe that you believe it would be immoral for them to publish anything in their life again). What's far more relevant here is just your personal self-interests, as a collaboration might reflect badly on you. Ethics are only an issue in the other cases, such as trying to cut them out and publish it under your name. Maybe this would be the better option for you (and the one you should take), but ethically it's not.

Comment: Withdrawing the name of Researcher B and then publishing without any other comment could be very damaging to the reputation of Researcher A, should it become common knowledge that B coauthored it. If Researcher A can verify that the hypotheses, experiments, results and conclusions are still solid - it can still be worth publishing - but not without mention of the situation and the extraordinary measures taken to secure the findings.

Comment: If the misconduct is academic, is it possible for you to independently verify the results done by Researcher B?  It may be possible to publish the results with a disclaimer that Researcher B's part has been independently verified (without Researcher B - or perhaps by a different group) to show that the results are not tainted by Researcher B.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, how is it different from my third option?

Comment: Ask your department chair.

Comment: @Mast, just out of curiosity, what makes you think I'm not a department chair?

Answer (score 46):

I expand on a comment by Buffy where this was hinted at:

It is a very different issue whether the misconduct was on the scientific level, which would cast doubt on the results, or on the social/moral level.

In the first case, it is difficult to trust the results if B is on the author list. Here, we have a serious dilemma. Probably OP might want to consider to cut their (and everybody's losses). Perhaps there is a way to publish it that makes it explicitly clear that this work has not been tainted by misconduct (editors note etc.).

To the second point:

Reiser's filesystem, Bieberbach's or Teichmüller's achievements are not devalued by their personal moral failings.

In this case, the research is done. It should be published. I do not know how important or impactful it is, but in principle, it's always a service to science and humanity, not just the respective taxpayer. Ultimately it's the OP's decision whether they are prepared to accept possible flak for their step. The research is separate from the authors behaviour. It's their detractors that would be trying to mix science and mores.

The only exception I can imagine for research to be suppressed for moral failures would be if the data were obtained in a clearly unethical way. The purpose of this is to discourage incentives for future breaking of ethical rules for obtaining it.

Comment: A filesystem is a code that can be tested by someone much less skilled than its author. A theorem is a sequence of arguments that can be understood and verified by someone with close skills and expertise as the author. Dishonest authors can quickly produce a stream of faked results, that will take years to verify and disprove. That's why academic reputation is so important.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Exactly. Scientific and extrascientific moral failures are of a different kind and should be treated separately. People can be highly flawed human beings, but their works may still be valid if their flaws are not on the professional level.

Comment: You and me can both understand perfectly well, but the opinion of the general public might differ. It is not unusual for people to distrust those who are different from them, by the color of their skin, or by their behaviour in personal affairs.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Yes, indeed. That's precisely why I make a specific remark taking into account whether the OP is ready to take flak for their position. The fundamental science-ethical question does not or should not - in my opinion - depend on the mob's reaction to it. What one chooses to do, will have to depend on personal courage, position, stage in career, freedom of operation and other factors. I wouldn't blame anyone for taking the safe route, but respect whoever takes the uncomfortable one.

Comment: I am wondering about the downvote - I am happy to correct a mistake or being shown a shortcoming in my argument, especially in such a difficult situation, but I'd really like to know what it is.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you could link to those people, since I've never heard of them

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- They are easily googled, but I am happy to link, however never done that on SE before.

Comment: I don't think those people (I don't know Reiser and can't find him quickly) are good examples: the other two were Nazis and after the 2nd world war, there was many years not much done against Nazis  except for political figures (Nazi scientists were often still in influential positions). And thus, it is today much"harder" to "erase" their contributions (even though e.g. a school named after the scientist Wernher von Braun recently changed the name). I'd guess it would be different if someone did misconduct today and the misconduct would came to light today.

Comment: The [Stanford Prison Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_prison_experiment) is a classic example of unethical research.

Comment: @user111388 Reiser was found guilty for murdering his wife. Googling "Reiser file system" gives his story on the wikipedia page as second result. I used Bieberbach and Teichmüller to offer concrete examples for research that should not be banned because of the people behind it even under today's criteria. This statement was completely independent of whether it would have been punished in their time. I thus stand by the example. (As aside: Teichmüller effectively "committed suicide" by volunteering for the Eastern Front).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: Let me clarify: I believe if someone did misconduct today, it would not affect his papers from 20 years ago which are already established. I do however believe, that his papers for the next years would be affected (people would not like to name something after them, would think bad of the coauthors, not nominating them for prices etc ). I do believe that the people you mentioned did their "misconduct" (Reiser) much later than their important research (or, in case of the Nazi scientists, their actions were seen as "wrong" much after their research, maybe in the 80s or 90s)

Comment: whileOP's coauthor (presumably) did their misconduct (close to) now. So, I cannot immediately see how those examples translate to OP's case. I hope you do understand my point even if you do not share it. Thank you for the information about Reiser, by the way!

Comment: I think this misses a social issue though: A great scientific paper can "whitewash" or "outshine" the moral disconduct if the the offending author is named. This is not intended, but humans have a hard time "separating author and content" will not count these as "different things" but weigh the academic success against the moral misconduct. Is this effect wanted?

Comment: @user111388 I need to clarify: in my view, the temporal distance of their misdeeds has nothing to do with Bieberbach's publication rights, were they also in the future. If a scientist with despicable opinions today would publish good work in an area not affected by their opinion, I would support publication, even if nothing else (prizes/honours). I find it highly problematic when moral judgement is confounded with achievement in a field which has nothing to do with it. When this is not respected, there is always the whiff of inquisition in the air.

Comment: @ljrk I guess if you apply that rule strictly to past researchers, you will have very few left standing. That will be one great culling. Elimination of achievements is one of the hallmarks of totalitarian ideologies. I believe to remember - but cannot reconstruct the case - that one of the totalitarian states of the 20th century did (try to) erase the achievement of an "undesirable" and instead attributed it to a ideologically amenable one. I.I.Rabi's advice to Feynman comes to mind, paraphrased: "Do not use something good that somebody does against that person, even if they have many vices."

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: Thank you for the clarification! I absolutely agree with you that this is how it should be - I don't believe, however, that humans can be so "perfect" not to mix academic and non-academic issues up. I'd wager to say that if a famous "Corona doesn't exist"-believing person would publish a great physics paper tomorrow, they would not get the credit they deserved.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I don't propose being "strict" here, it's simply something to keep in mind.  Moreover, this is mostly relevant to people still alive rather than dead. E.g., I wouldn't publish a paper co-authored with leaders of the Nazi party, even if it is relevant to my field, as I would give those people a platform to spread their fascism. I just want to stress that "research is separate from the authors behavior" isn't that clear cut of a formula.

Comment: @ljrk Ok, I understand now. As an individual, I would agree with you and likely act the same. As a society/collective, I am strongly against blocking a person otherwise (i.e. not scientifically) morally failed (according to my or society's view) from participating in the scientific discourse. It gets subtle when people with an ideologised perspective write about ethnology, economy, politics, evolution, but that's a boundary case, and thus a different discussion; and it is unlikely to come as a surprise to the collaborator.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Oh, yes, I definitely wouldn't want legislation on that or similar.

Comment: @Buffy The Stanford Prison Experiment is not just unethical. It is a what-you-put-in-is-what-you-get-out, or shorter garbage-in-garbage-out "experiment". Of course, if you instruct people to unleash the sadist in oneself, etc., no surprise that this is what you get. It is completely unclear how tainted the behaviour of the participants is against what they were told to do. It's useless in addition to evil.

Answer (score 12):

Recommend publishing in both authors true names and modify the paper to include information to make it easier to verify the results. Make the data sets available, publish all the source code, etc. Don't hold anything back.

Comment: Arguably, this is what any paper is expected to include these days.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: Yes, but the answer makes a good point: whatever the field’s expected level of transparency is, it makes sense in this situation to go beyond these expectations and aim for an especially high standard.

Answer (score 7):

In your question you considered the pros and contras of all approaches. For example, when you considered the option **not publish at all**, the main counter-arguments are that Researcher A does not benefit, taxpayer's money are wasted, and community does not benefit from the results. Let me discuss them in a little more details.

- Taxpayers are not benefitting from the *results* of the research directly. They benefit from the *impact* of this research: the practical outcomes, embodied in more effective tools, processes and products.
- Research community and the surrounding community of engineers, enterpreneurs, buisiness people, etc, pick up promising results and take them further towards development and impact. For this to happen, the results need to be clearly communicated, promising, and *trustworthy*. People are not likely to invest time and resources in results they can't trust.
- Researcher B commited an academic misconduct and compromised their *reputation*. The compromised reputation taints the trustworthiness of all their results, past and future. As a co-author, Researcher A might know that the results of their joint paper are not affected and trustworthy. But for the community and general public establishing the trustworthiness is not simple, and they have to rely on reputation instead. Unless Researcher A has a lot of reputational credit (i.e. they are Professor Famous), their word alone is not sufficient to wipe the negativity brought by the Researcher B being part of the team.

Perhaps, the best course of action would be not to publish the research done together with the Researcher B. Instead, Researcher A should use the skills they learnt while working on this project to obtain new results and benefit their career. Finding right people for collaboration is one of critically important skills for success in academia.

Comment: That's a good point, though not all types of misconduct compromise B's credibility as a researcher.

Comment: @Kostya_I Even if B's misconduct does not compromise them in A's eyes, the views of the general public might differ.

Comment: Actually, after some thought I don't really understand your argument. The ethical pressure to publish stems from A's belief that they have something valuable to give to the community/humanity. How does the fact that the community/humanity might be unwilling to take it affect this at all? If the research fails to make impact it merits,  at least A tried. What is gained by not trying?

Comment: So, A believes they have a valuable gift for the people. But people don't really trust that the gift is safe, and don't want it. But A believes the gift is valuable and safe, and people are just not very smart to see it. So A forces the gift down people's throats. *At least A tried. What is gained by not trying?*

Comment: publishing a scientific paper is not forcing anyone anything, even to read it, much less take down their throat. And it is not granted that people "don't really trust the gift is safe and don't want it" before the paper is published. While people might use authors' credibility as a proxy, eventually scientific papers are evaluated on their merits. Important or promising findings will be independently verified/replicated, and it's by definition not true that people don't want it.

Comment: As a reviewer, I am often asked to read papers and evaluate them. I am not happy to waste my time on reading fake results produced by dishonest authors. Similarly, readers can be frustrated to read something which is later retracted because one of the authors can not be trusted.

Comment: @Kostya_I: The counter-argument to your “ethical pressure to publish” is that the value to science of this one piece of research is (arguably) outweighed by the value of maintaining ethical standards by consistently punishing scientific misconduct.

Answer (score 7):

**Publish your contributions as separate sole author papers**

- note this will only be possible in some scenarios, but it is important to present this option, because it is often the best one when it is possible

Remove the content contributed by the offending co-author and publish the partial work without them (most likely in a lower impact journal). This may not be possible if your independent contributions (your ideas, analyses, and writing) do not make up a significant contribution to the literature without the content from the other author. But often the partial work is worth publishing, even if not as complete as you would like it to be. Also you might be able to take the work in a slightly different direction with a minor revision.

This solution is actually quite generous to the co-author because they are then free to publish their contribution as a separate publication, alone, as well. They can build off of your work, and additionally you get a citation. Science suffers the least in this solution. The only cost to readers is the mental cost of having to read and find the work in 2 papers rather than one. While your paper may be less impactful than the original piece, a sole author publication can also be beneficial on the CV. This solution means you get to avoid the negative consequences of the association, but you ethically aren't doing anything wrong either. If you want to be really transparent you can even add in the acknowledgements that you are grateful for conversations with X on dates Y to Z. Note if Y - Z is before the scandal is revealed, it also provides evidence that these conversations occurred before when you might be made aware of the scandal. In addition, almost no one on hiring committees looks at the acknowledgements on your papers. So your reputation would be quite safe here.

You should of course discuss this with your co-author, but they might be more likely to cooperate with this approach than some of the other options. But ethically, this is the only option (besides not publishing) where you can proceed even without your co-author's permission, as long as you don't publish their contributions. Be sure to save all emails from the collaboration, so you can prove that these were your ideas.

Comment: The OP doesn't give details about the field or the particular project, but in nearly all truly collaborative projects, it wouldn't be feasible to carve out papers separately from it, based solely upon author contributions. Neither paper would likely be comprehensive or coherent, and hence independently publishable. So this doesn't seem like a generalised answer to the question.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill In nearly all purely theoretical or computational fields, which is a quite expansive set of disciplines, this can be an option. As you mention the OP doesn't state their field, so it's important to provide answers that would work in various different fields, not just fields with lab or field based experimental work. Additionally, the answer specifically states "This may not be possible if your independent contributions do not make up a significant contribution to the literature without the content from the other author"

Comment: “In nearly all purely theoretical or computational fields […] this can be an option.” What fields do you have in mind?  At least in my experience of pure maths and theoretical CS, it is pretty rare that a collaboration can be disentangled to this extent.

Comment: @PLL I'm thinking mathematical/compuational biology, engineering, physics and other math modelling disciplines. Often a purer paper describing the model and proving some the model's properties could easily be published in an applied math journal, where as an applied paper that uses the model to answer some novel applied questions might go in a science journal. The combined paper might be a very high impact general science paper, but the two papers are easily disentangled, especially if the authors cooperate.

Answer (score 3):

### Publish under pseudonym(s)

One or both of you could use pseudonyms. As with all other options, this is a compromise, but in this case you're emphasising getting the publicly funded and/or important research out there, while avoiding further association with a person you don't want to be associated with, and not allowing them further credit, while also not tarnishing the research by association with their name. Of course it would be improper to force them to publish under a pseudonym, so it's still their choice, and if they didn't agree then it might be obvious who you are if you're continuing previous work.

Comment: This may well be considered unethical in its own right, because the effect is to directly dodge the negative reputation of B. Think about what happens when it's revealed that "C" is actually B, to the reputation of A.

Comment: @obscurans to be clear the model I have in my head is B discovered to have committed serious sexual misconduct, or murder or something else beyond academia. A & B have pending work close to publication which is of some significance, and A & B both agree to publish pseudonymously then sever ties. I might be wrong, but I think that if both A & B were exposed, "I thought this work was important but that B's reputation should not benefit from publishing it" would be acceptable as a defence.

Comment: I think it's not a good solution for academic misconduct such as fabricating results, since even if A believes that this particular paper isn't tainted they might be wrong, and separating it from B makes that harder to uncover. It's a case by case thing but I do think there are situations in which it would be an appropriate move

Comment: But if B's crime was non-academic misconduct, it doesn't diminish their scientific credit. Nobody should ever collaborate with B again, but their results are their own, and their past ones still stand. Unlike in general publishing, pseudonyms just don't work well in science, where the actual authors' names, rightly or wrongly, carry extreme importance. There's also stuff like "how do I contact the author for info".

Comment: @obscurans pseudonyms have been used in science for as long as science has existed. Knuth once published pseudonymously precisely to ensure that his paper was reviewed properly, and not just by the strength of his name. Sure, they're not ideal, but they're not inherently unethical or unworkable and it's ultimately up to the authors in such a situation to decide whether it's an appropriate solution or not.

Comment: Yes they have been used. *In a situation where you're deliberately dodging negative reputation*... I think you'll have a hard time defending it.

Comment: @obscurans "..if B's crime was nonacademic, it doesn't diminish their credit": The problem seems to be that I (and OP, and this answerer) believe this is not true as you get evaluated by people (who are driven by emotions), not by machines. Of course, if there is a time gap of 10 years between the research and the misconduct, those feelings have probably diminished. But if you sleep with my wife today, I will not be able to review your papee next month properly, no matter how much I try (and no matter how much at fault my wife is and you are not). I belive that if, say, Jana aus Kassel

Comment: would write a famous literature paper tomorrow, it would not get the credit it deserves and also not her coauthor because she says stupid things unrelated to literature. in 10 years, it would be better. Here a pseusonym could absolutely be useful. Whether it is ethical is another question.

Comment: I think this problem is better solved with blind (and better yet double-blind) reviewing, not just pseudonyms when something that needs hiding exists (either positive or negative reputation). I purely meant B's *scientific* credit doesn't change, and if someone develops conflict of interest/partiality based on it they probably should recuse as reviewer anyway.

Comment: Publishing under pseudonyms takes credit away from the authors. Researcher A has no right to take the credit away from Researcher B. And to take if from himself would be stupid.

Comment: @obscurans: The author may not be able to propose double blind reviewing (if this is not a thing in the field). Also, if B does something bad against society as a whole (terrorism, giving dangerous advice about Corona in public, being a leading figure of a dictatorship), all reviewers are pribably biased, most of them not even noticing it.

Comment: @Tomas it wouldn't be stupid at all if the other researchers name is damaged enough. Like it or not working with people who are suspected or accused of, for example, sexual impropriety or even crimes will reflect extremely poorly on you.  You will be seen as an enabler.  Myself, unless it was really important work I would cut my losses and hope I never get associated with the other person for any reason.

Answer (score -2):

**Publish the result jointly with B as planned.** There is no hesitation here. If you want ethics, here's a teaching from the Bible [Matthew 22:15-21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+22%3A15-21&version=NIV):

> Give to Caesar what is Caesar’s, and to God what is God’s.

Did Researcher B contribute his value to the study? Yes, he did, according to what you said.

Did Researcher B commit any crime within your joint study? Faked results, etc.? No, he didn't, according to what you said.

So, the reward of having the result jointly published with you (under his real name, for god's sake) is his, isn't it?

It's not your place to judge him or to take this from him - you are not the judge, right? Not even judge should have that right. Should all your contributions and credits be deleted when you commit a crime? Does it sound like justice?

Now, to your concerns:

> The ethical drawback is that it can be perceived as siding with B in
> the scandal/breaching a boycott, and the practical one is that
> Researcher A's career might suffer from association with the scandal.

OMG... this is based on a fear of being judged by a very sick society. Only very sick minded society would make these judgements.

You have to make a choice, if your decision shall be driven by real ethics, or fear of being judged by sick minded people.

Comment: Yet, people in this society are "very sick". People are usually driven by emotions. I sincerly believe that a physics paper from someone who publicitly says Corona doesn't exist and people should meet and kiss a lot and cough onto each other would not be properly credited, by (mostly unconsicous) biases people have.

Comment: @user111388 that wouldn't be science then, that would be (rather dirty) politics. Scientist should have enough ethics to pursue the truth and make his decisions free of politic bullshit.

Comment: @user111388 and yes, some people in this society are very sick, but do you want to take part in spreading that sickness with unethical decisions?

Comment: The bible also says things like _"A man or a woman who is a medium or a spiritist must be put to death. They are to be stoned; their blood is on their own hands"_ if anything quoting it in reference to ethics is just muddying the waters here. If you have a valid point from an academic point of view you're welcome to bring that forward instead.

Comment: No, but I don't think one should take this so easy and give more concern to the fact that almost everybody is "sick" (in the way you define). Your answer sounds more like the world should be - I'd say the world's scientists are much more "rather dirty politics" than you seem to believe.

Comment: You seem to think that a decision not to have anything to do with a person because of their moral failures can only be taken out of a fear of a mythical "very sick society", but that is merely a convenient way to denounce such a decision without a need to address its ethical substance.

Comment: @Kostya_I could you please expand on the ethical substance of that decision? Because I do not see anything ethical on taking away credits from a person based on his crimes unrelated to your joint work, as I mentioned.

Comment: @Tomas, by refusing to publish jointly with B, A does not *"take away"* anything from B. Rather, they refuse to *give* B what's rightfully A's. I explicitly acknowledged in my post that, in my opinion, B retains the right to credit for their part of the work. But if that part cannot be separated and published under B's name only, and thus B has difficulties claiming that credit, that's not A's problem.